# Table spacing, multi column

Tags: tables, spacing, multicolumn

I am trying to construct a table, but the spacing isn't balanced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c| }

\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Class} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Similarity Gibbs Sampling} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Hand Computatation} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Combination} & \multirow{2}{*}{Graph Cut(S)} \\ \cline{2-1} \cline{3-1} \cline{4-1} \cline{5-1} \cline{6-1} \cline{7-1} \cline{8-1} \cline{9-1}
& 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \\ \hline
${V_1}$ & 0.388 & 0.612 & 0.393 & 0.607 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ \hline
${V_2}$ & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
${V_3}$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\ \hline
${V_4}$ & 0.388 & 0.612 & 0.393 & 0.607 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
%\cline{2-1} 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the 3rd column and 5th column do not share the same spacing as 2nd and 4th respectively.

Comment: have a look at the `tabularx` package, and also the `siunitx` package for help with decimal alignment (and more)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to the issue with the widths of columns 3 and 5 not being the same as those of columns 2 and 4, respectively, I'd say your table has a second issue: The horizontal lines you're trying to draw between the first and second header rows touch each other and thus don't provide visual clues as to how the columns are grouped. (This is a shortcoming caused by the properties of `\cline` which can't be remedied easily short of using a different group of line-drawing commands -- see below for an alternative.)

- To fix the first issue, you could use the [tabularx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package and its `X` column type to guarantee equal widths of columns 2 through 5. By default, material in a column of type `X` is set left-justified (ragged-right); in the example below I define a new column type, `Y`, which is a center-set version of `X`.
- The second issue is best addressed, I believe, by using the line-drawing commands of the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package. In particular, the command `\cmidrule` can serve to draw short "trimmed" horizontal lines that don't touch. Other benefits of using the rule-drawing comamnds of the `booktabs` package is that the spacing above and below the lines is *much* better than what you'll get with `\hline` and `\cline` and that the rules aren't all equally thick, making for a much more interesting-looking table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
  \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % choose page parameters best for your document
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{4}{Y} *{5}{c} @{}}
\toprule
Class & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Similarity Gibbs Sampling} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Hand Computation} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Combination} & 
Graph Cut(S) \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} % left- and right-trimming
& 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \\ 
\midrule
${V_1}$ & 0.388 & 0.612 & 0.393 & 0.607 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2\\ 
${V_2}$ & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
${V_3}$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 
${V_4}$ & 0.388 & 0.612 & 0.393 & 0.607 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a million!!! Thanks for your generosity, thanks for your kindness, thanks for your advice and thanks for your time!!! God bless you!!