# columns have not the same size although centered

Tags: tables

I made a table like this one

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \centering
        \caption{Reproduzierbarkeit der Elektroden}
        \begin{tabular}{ccccc|c|c|c|c|}
            \toprule
                \textbf{Elektrode} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Mittelwert [mV]}} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{maximale Abweichung [\%]}} \\  
            \midrule
                &pH 6 &pH 7 & pH 8 &pH 9 &pH 6 &pH 7 &pH 8&pH 9\\
            \cmidrule[0.5pt]{2-9}
                 6 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 11\\
                 7 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 11\\
                 8 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 11\\
                 9 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 11\\
            \bottomrule
            \label{tab:reproduzierbarkeit}
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

and what I get is:

[image]

So why is the width of the ninth column bigger than the others, although all rows are centered?
How can I change this, so that each column has the same width?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the width of the last column? It's because of the `\multicolumn` above I'd think, it is wider than the four columns below, so additional width is added to the last column. (Edit: rows are horizontal, columns are vertical.)

Comment: Oh sorry, I changed it. Yes I mean the width. How can I fix it, that they are equal?

Comment: It is basically the same problem as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128736/table-spacing-multi-column/128754#128754 I think, you could try using Mico's suggestion.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  I think you can do it without `tabularx` and without needing to know the overall width of the tabular. Does my deleted-edited-undeleted answer do what's wanted here? (I'm not sure if it is quite right...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the spanned cells are wider than the multicolumn entry.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \centering
        \newcommand\x{\makebox[1pt]{}}
        \caption{Reproduzierbarkeit der Elektroden}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c*4{>\x c<\x}|*4{>\x c<\x|}@{}}
            \toprule
                \textbf{Elektrode} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Mittelwert [mV]}} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{maximale Abweichung [\%]}} \\  
            \midrule
                &pH 6 &pH 7 & pH 8 &pH 9 &pH 6 &pH 7 &pH 8&pH 9\\
            \cmidrule[0.5pt]{2-9}
                 6 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 11\\
                 7 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 11\\
                 8 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 11\\
                 9 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 11\\
            \bottomrule
            \label{tab:reproduzierbarkeit}
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks, fixed and image updated:-)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this. I don't know which ones exactly you want equal in width. This makes the final four columns of equal width using a new column type, `H`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,calc}
\newlength{\origtabcolsep}
\setlength{\origtabcolsep}{\tabcolsep}
\newlength{\mycolswidth}
\settowidth{\mycolswidth}{\textbf{maximale Abweichung [\%]}}
\newlength{\mycolwidth}
\setlength{\mycolwidth}{.25\mycolswidth-.75\tabcolsep}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\mycolwidth}|}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htb]
      \centering
      \caption{Reproduzierbarkeit der Elektroden}
      \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.75\origtabcolsep}
      \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}|*{4}{H}}
          \toprule
              \textbf{Elektrode} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Mittelwert [mV]}} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{maximale Abweichung [\%]}} \\
          \midrule
              &pH 6 &pH 7 & pH 8 &pH 9 &pH 6 &pH 7 &pH 8&pH 9\\
          \cmidrule[0.5pt]{2-9}
               6 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 11\\
               7 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 11\\
               8 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 11\\
               9 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 111 & 10 & 12 & 13 & 11\\
          \bottomrule
          \label{tab:reproduzierbarkeit}
      \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tabular using new column type, H, for final 4 columns]

Comment: That looks better, though the table is a bit wider than `\textwidth`, leading to an overfull box. (Sorry for being difficult to please.)  Oh, and if you add `\arraybackslash` after `\centering` in the definition of `H` you can use `\\ ` to start new table rows.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes. I think it should be `\tabcolsep` rather than `\arraycolsep`. That helps a bit but I think there's some other spacing there I'm not getting. Thanks for pointing out `\arraybackslash` - that's a command I didn't even know to look for.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This version seems to avoid that at the cost of squeezing the tabular slightly. The overfull box is caused by the combination of `array` and the vertical lines since `array` allows them their natural width...