# Proper multi column spacing

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx

I run into a simple problem but i cant finde a solution to it..
I want to create a matrix where all elements in a row have a equal width. Like this:

[image: Aim of the table]

My approach was 12 columns (+1 initial column) and then to work with multicolumns. The problem I get is that the rows are not scaled to the same width as in this picture.

[image]

I tried tabularx as in this question but it did not work as desired. (Using 12 times X as header) [Table spacing, multi column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128736/table-spacing-multi-column)

Can someone explain to me where the error is that tabularx doesn't work either?

Code for the simple tabel environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|cllcclclccll|}
\hline
N & \multicolumn{12}{c|}{Chance}                                                                                  \\ \hline
1 & \multicolumn{12}{c|}{100}                                                                                     \\ \hline
2 & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{50}                               & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{50}                               \\ \hline
3 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{22}             & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{56}            & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{22}            \\ \hline
4 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{12.5} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{37.5} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{37.5} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{12.5} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Edited to be compilable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With fixed width columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newlength{\blockwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

% local settings
\setlength{\blockwidth}{0.5cm}
\newcommand{\block}[2]{% #1 = number of blocks to span, #2 = text
  \multicolumn{#1}{w{c}{\dimeval{#1\blockwidth+10\arrayrulewidth*\f{#1}/#1}}|}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\f}[1]{\inteval{4*(#1-3)}}
%%%

\begin{tabular}{|>{$\vphantom{\bigg|}}c<{$}|*{12}{c}}
\hline
N & \block{12}{Chance} \\ \hline
1 & \block{12}{100} \\ \hline
2 & \block{6}{50} & \block{6}{50} \\ \hline
3 & \block{4}{22} & \block{4}{56} & \block{4}{22} \\ \hline
4 & \block{3}{12.5} & \block{3}{37.5} & \block{3}{37.5} & \block{3}{12.5} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{A caption}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably a Ti*k*Z based approach is better, for this case. Or maybe even a tree rather than a table.

Comment: Thanks, that was what i was looking for. TikZ would have been a good idear i didn't think of. You got any idear why tabularx with somthing on the lines of "\begin{tabularx}{5cm}{|X|X|...|X|X|}" didnt work?

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun:

`\multicolumn` puts all the "extra" space into the last column used, and a lot of these columns are never used individually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|XXXXXXXXXXXX|}
\hline
 &&&&&&&&&&&& \\[-\normalbaselineskip]% hidden
N & \multicolumn{12}{c|}{Chance}                                                                                  \\ \hline
1 & \multicolumn{12}{c|}{100}                                                                                     \\ \hline
2 & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{50}                               & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{50}                               \\ \hline
3 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{22}             & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{56}            & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{22}            \\ \hline
4 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{12.5} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{37.5} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{37.5} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{12.5} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but if you want the boxes to be proportional in size to the numbers, you could use Ti*k*Z `chains`. Basically, the first column is a chain called `n` going below, and each numbered row is a chain going right. There is no error checking, so your rows could be shorter or longer than 100.

You can change the value of `\widthfactor` to adjust the width of the table.

[image]

There is also an optional argument that can set Ti*k*Z options for the entire table, for example:

```
\chancetable[thick, orange, text=blue]{{100},{50,50},{22,56,22},{12.5,37.5,37.5,12.5}}
```

would work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\newcommand{\widthfactor}{1}

\tikzset{rect/.style={draw, minimum width=#1, minimum height=5mm, inner sep=0pt}}

\newcommand{\chancetable}[2][]{\tikz[node distance=-\pgflinewidth, #1]{
    \node[rect=\widthfactor*5mm, start chain=n going below](N0){N}; \node[rect=\widthfactor*100mm, right=of N0]{Chance};
    \foreach \r[count=\n, evaluate=\n as \k using {int(\n-1)}] in {#2} {
        \node[rect=\widthfactor*5mm, below=of N\k, start chain=\n, on chain=\n](N\n){\n};
        \foreach \p in \r {\node[on chain=\n, rect=\widthfactor*\p mm]{\p};} 
    }
}}

\begin{document}

\chancetable{{100},{50,50},{22,56,22},{12.5,37.5,37.5,12.5}}

\end{document}
```